# How do I use widgets to add an attribute to a form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm trying to get a placeholder to show up for a form field but I'm doing something wrong with my form fields. Any thoughts? I've got the following classes:

```
class EditField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'id':'editor'})
        self.label  = _('content')

class EditField_typeA(EditField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditField_typeA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def clean(self, value):
        if not (len(re.sub('[ ]{2,}', ' ', value)) < settings.FORM_MIN):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('content must be %s') % settings.FORM_MIN)
        return value

class FinalForm(forms.Form):
    foo  = FooField()
    bar  = BarField()
    text   = EditField_typeA()

    def __init__(self, data=None, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FinalForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

        ## THIS IS THE PART THAT ISN'T WORKING    
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Fill this in' 

        if int(user.reputation) < settings.CAPTCHA_IF_REP_LESS_THAN and not (user.is_superuser or user.is_staff):
            spam_fields = call_all_handlers('create_anti_spam_field')
            if spam_fields:
                spam_fields = dict(spam_fields)
                for name, field in spam_fields.items():
                    self.fields[name] = field

                self._anti_spam_fields = spam_fields.keys()
            else:
                self._anti_spam_fields = []
```

I'm guessing that I'm using widget wrong, or in the wrong place. Can't find the right part of the widget docs to explain what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: What error it throws? Try it with `self.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Fill this in'})`

Comment: @AamirAdnan that worked! But could you please help me understand why?